# Delay time til user can run a php script again

Tags: php

I've searched a lot and didn't found a simply answer, all i need is dont allow user to run the same php script too fast, like if he sent the form, i need to block the same form to be runned again for 10 seconds.

I tried using:

```
     if(isset($_SESSION['var']){
            exit;
         }
```

and setting the var on the start of the script and then unsetting it on script finish, but it will only disallow him to run the script while it's currently running, is there any way to do this?

Comment: you can store last visit time in session and compare it with current time

Comment: How secure does it have to be? You can set a cookie with a lifetime of 10 seconds. If cookie exist on user browser block it. Cookies will persist even if user exits page and comes back, unlike session

Comment: it doesn't have to be secure, it's just a precaution to user dont send a transaction twice by double clicking...

Comment: `if($_SESSION['var'] < strtotime( '-10 second' )){` Where `$_SESSION['var'] `== time of last request

Comment: Andres, i'll search about it, may u give me a example?

Comment: In that case either way works. Session is probably easier to set up

Answer (score 1):

You can use Timeout to prevent user run script to fast ,
But php use Session to store Timeout like this :

```
session_start(); //At the beginning of the PHP file

define("TIMEOUT", 10); //10 sec

//Check timeout
if (isset($_SESSION['expire'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['expire']-time()>TIMEOUT) {
        unset($_SESSION['expire']);
    }   
}

//Allow to do submit after 10 sec
if (!isset($_SESSION['expire'])) {
    $_SESSION['expire']=time();

    //Your submit code
}
```